# Rails throwing a Redis::TimeoutError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I have tried twice to install an installation of RubyMine on a CentOS7 VM. They have now both failed due to a Redis::TimeoutError.

I have received this error when attempting to start the rails server. This happens both through RubyMine and through the Konsole after I start redis through the "service redis start" command.

I can start the rails server fine without starting redis first. And the application works fine (so far) if I start redis after the server starts. However this is only a short term solution as I will be adding automatic start for all services such as redis when my VM starts.

My backtrace

```
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:111:in `rescue in _write_to_socket': Connection timed out (Redis::TimeoutError)
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:104:in `_write_to_socket'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:131:in `block in write'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:130:in `loop'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:130:in `write'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:374:in `write'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/client.rb:271:in `block in write'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/client.rb:250:in `io'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/client.rb:269:in `write'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/client.rb:228:in `block (3 levels) in process'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/client.rb:222:in `each'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/client.rb:222:in `block (2 levels) in process'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/client.rb:367:in `ensure_connected'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/client.rb:221:in `block in process'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/client.rb:306:in `logging'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/client.rb:220:in `process'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/client.rb:120:in `call'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.16.2.321/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/redis.rb:42:in `block in call'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.16.2.321/lib/new_relic/agent/datastores.rb:111:in `wrap'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.16.2.321/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/redis.rb:41:in `call'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis.rb:754:in `block in set'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis.rb:58:in `block in synchronize'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis.rb:58:in `synchronize'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis.rb:750:in `set'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-store-1.1.7/lib/redis/store/interface.rb:9:in `set'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-store-1.1.7/lib/redis/store/ttl.rb:8:in `set'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-store-1.1.7/lib/redis/store/marshalling.rb:5:in `block in set'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-store-1.1.7/lib/redis/store/marshalling.rb:29:in `_marshal'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-store-1.1.7/lib/redis/store/marshalling.rb:5:in `set'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-store-1.1.7/lib/redis/store/namespace.rb:5:in `block in set'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-store-1.1.7/lib/redis/store/namespace.rb:74:in `namespace'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-store-1.1.7/lib/redis/store/namespace.rb:5:in `set'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:223:in `block in write_entry'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:212:in `call'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:212:in `with'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:223:in `write_entry'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:60:in `block in write'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/cache.rb:547:in `block in instrument'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/cache.rb:547:in `instrument'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:58:in `write'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/st_core-1.5.0.2/lib/st_core/entity_factory/entity_store.rb:105:in `write'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/st_core-1.5.0.2/lib/st_core/entity_factory/entity_store.rb:54:in `store'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/st_core-1.5.0.2/lib/st_core/engine.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/st_core-1.5.0.2/lib/st_core/engine.rb:62:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
from /root/RubymineProjects/chop/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /root/RubymineProjects/chop/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
```

Answer (score 0):

I hava a same problem when I create redis-cluster.Finally,I find the problem.
you should do that:
1、gem uninstall redis
2、gem install redis --version 3.0.0